# How much torque do I need to spin my keys inside a keyhole

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I am working in a project to open a door using microcontrollers. I will couple a motor with my keys.

My doubt is: I don't know how to find the necessary torque of my motor so my project could work properly. In my case, the keys will be always inside the keyhole.

Comment: Do you mean you don't know the equation for torque, or is it more the engineering details?

Comment: It is more the engineering details

Comment: This http://engineering.stackexchange.com/ site might have a better chance of an answer

Comment: I don's see how we can answer this since keys/locks vary enormously in how stiff they are to turn. Why not try your own door lock and measure the torque required.

Answer (score 1):

Selecting the correct motor for an application is always a difficult task. In my experience, there are always some back of the envelope approximations. Of the different ways to go about this, I can think of two that will work well. The first, is to measure the torque required with a pulling force scale, like this: [image: Newton scale, courtesy of ScienceLabSupplies.com]

They're simple and inexpensive. There are other more DIY ways to measure force but those need calibration and aren't worth the effort. Fasten a long lever to your key, in a T-shape. Not the simplest thing in the world to fasten together, consider perhaps clamping to the key with two levers.

Then, turn the key in the lock using the force scale on the tip of one side of the lever, and measure the force it takes to turn the key. Average a few trials to get an idea, then use the force and lever length (1/2 the total lever length) and calculate torque (= Fd).

Another option, which is more practical/engineering-y, is to select a motor that will supply enough torque for the application based on experience. Good small DC motor distributors are Mouser, Digikey, Jameco, All Electronics, or ebay. Good motor brands are Mabuchi, NMB, SDP/SI, Buehler, and Maxon. That should give you places to start looking.

Choosing the motor torque, I usually go from the following scale:

**0.28 oz-in  (0.002 Nm)** ------- DC hobby motors, very weak, typically specified in g-cm (0.28 oz-in is 20 g-cm)

**40 oz-in    (0.26 Nm)** ------- Typical NEMA17 stepper motor torque, enough to turn a typical doorknob

**1232 oz-in  (8.69 Nm)** ------- High torque, enough to drive a full-table CNC gantry (the part that moves across the table carrying the mill)

**7,000 oz-in  (50 Nm)** ------- Higher torque, more than enough for many applications. For example, 18V electric drills.

**24,000 oz-in (170 Nm)** ------- Really high torque, very expensive motors. Put out enough torque to break a human neck (yikes).

**60,000 to 100,000+ oz-in** ------- Torque of the electric motor in a Tesla model S

Based on this information, any 40 to 200 oz-in motors will be sufficient for this application (0.26 to 1.4 Nm).

Comment: oh God the units

Comment: Yea, the halting torque of motors is always specified in different units, usually Nm, oz-in, or g-cm, but sometimes N-cm or others. It's a real pain.

Answer (score 0):

I would think this is highly dependent on how lubricated your keyhole is, and which type it is.  Let us for the sake of argument assume that it is so lubricated that any friction can be ignored and that your key is a simple spring lock, such that the torque applied by the lock on the key is Hookean.  That is,
$$
\tau_\text{lock} = k (\theta - \theta_0).
$$
In other words, the torque grows linearly with the angle with which you turn the key.  In that case, you simply need to find the minimum torque required to balance the key in an unlocked position, without breaking the key or the lock.  My suggestion, if you don't want to waste money on a bunch of different motors to try them out, would be to find a way to attach your key to some kind of long lever, in a manner that will not bend or break the key.  Make sure that the lever is sticking out equally much on both sides, such that the lever, by itself, does not exert a torque on the key due to gravity.

Then make sure that the lever is pointing straight out horisontally in the unlocked state, and find a reasonably heavy object and attach it somewhere on the lever.  By varying the distance from center, you will now be applying a torque, which is equal to:
$$
\tau_\text{you} = m g r,
$$
where $m$ is the mass of the object, $g$ is the gravitational acceleration—better to assume it's 10 m/s$^2$, in order to make sure you don't undershoot the mark—and $r$ is the distance from the key to the weight on the lever.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use a [torque wrench](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque_wrench) to measure it?

You would need one designed for low tension however. I don't even know if there are some for such low tension.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the lock. If it is a tumble key lock then it works like this:

[image: key]

The worst case torque would correspond with the highest friction on all pins, as well as the longest moment arm. The answer would be $$\tau = 5 \mu F_s r$$ where $\mu=0.15 \ldots 0.3$ is the coefficient of friction for brass or aluminum, $F_s$ the spring force when fully compressed (I have no clue what it is) and $r$ the radius of the rotating part of the lock. This is where the friction is applied.